# Sending image data to Flask restplus API with Python

Tags: python, api, rest, flask, flask-restful

I am creating an API with flask_restplus and am having some issues with receiving image files.
I have created a ReqParser that has a file argument and am trying to save it. I am also sending a PUT request from an image file on local pc (as opposed to a url). However, when I attempt to save the file in the put method, I get 'NoneType' so I am sure I am sending it wrong.
**API:**

```
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
usr_inv_args = reqparse.RequestParser()
usr_inv_args.add_argument("email", type=str, help="Account email")
usr_inv_args.add_argument("username", type=str, help="Account username")
usr_inv_args.add_argument('firstpic', type=werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage, location='files', help="first pic")
class HelloWorld(Resource):
    def put(self, name):
        args = usr_inv_args.parse_args()
        stream = args['firstpic']
        stream.save("firstpictest.jpg")

api.add_resource(HelloWorld, "/helloworld/<string:name>")
```

and this is how I am sending the request through a different directory:
**test.py**

```
import requests
BASE = R'http://127.0.0.1:5000'
files = {'image': open(r'sf90.jpg', 'rb')}
response = requests.put(BASE + 'helloworld/jared', {'email': 'jared', 'username':'zwick', 'firstpic': files['image']})

print(response)
```

Note: While running both applications simultaneously I am able to retrieve email and username arguments, the file storage however has had me banging my head on my desk all day :) Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, if anyone in the future is experiencing the same. I used a POST request instead of a PUT and it worked just fine.